# dreamweaver CS5 recordset not filtering on $_SESSION variable

Tags: php, dreamweaver

I'm trying to filter records base on a $_SESSION Variable.
I have a simple form that posts the user name and password to a results.php page which contains:

```
 <?php
 session_start ();
 $_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['user_name'];
 echo $_SESSION['username'];


 ?>
```

This works ok and echos the user name on the page:

I then want to filter a record set and return the user_id based the $_SESSION['username'];

I have a recordset filter setup (see attached) but it will not return any records - test says no data...

[image]

I have printed the statement which says SELECT user_id FROM `user` WHERE user_name = '-1' so its not picking up the Session variable - I have been working on this for sometime and cant solve the problem - any ideas where I'm going wrong.

Comment: the problem is you're using dreamweaver

Comment: yes t think your right... i have now coded it by hand using the following :<?php

$_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['user_name'];
echo $_SESSION['username'];
 
  $query = "SELECT user_id FROM user WHERE user_name = '" . $_SESSION['username'] . "'";
    
  
  $skillsets = mysql_query($query);
  if (!$skillsets) {
 
 die("Database connection failed;" . mysql_error());
  }
  
  
 
  $skills = mysql_fetch_array($skillsets);
  
 $_SESSION['userid'] = $skills ['user_id'];
 echo $_SESSION['userid'];
 
?>
thanks

Answer (score 0):

Dreamweaver stores a session variable named exactly as '**MM_Username**' that contains the login form username value.
Syntax is important, **u** is **UPPER** case.

So your runtime value must be:

```
$_SESSION['MM_Username']
```